# query to find out the number of first answers by a user in a Q&A website using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem in writing the query for this. I have a q&a website where I want to find out the number of first answers by a user - for all the questions answered by a user, which answers were the first for the particular question.

I have two tables -

- questions - id, question
- answers - id, question_id, answering_userid, date

I have broken this into two steps

1. find out the answers by a user

   - SELECT id FROM answers WHERE answering_userid = "ABC"
2. find out if they are the first

   - ????? This is where I am having problem. I have figured that it will employ MIN(date).

Can somebody help me in implementing this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of another user `codefly` I have got the answer I was looking for.

```
select a.id, a.answering_userid
from answers a
inner join (
   select answering_userid, question_id, min(date) as mindate
   from answers
   group by question_id
) first on a.question_id = first.question_id 
    and a.date = first.mindate
    and a.answering_userid = first.answering_userid
where a.answering_userid = "ABC"
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
select a.id, a.answering_userid
from answers a
inner join (
   select answering_userid, question_id, min(date) as mindate
   from answers
   group by answering_userid, question_id
) first on a.question_id = first.question_id 
    and a.date = first.mindate
    and a.answering_userid = first.answering_userid
```

Note that this will return dupes if you have 2 answers at the exact same moment.
Also, this is completely untested.

Comment: Thanks. I got the answer with a little tinkering to your answer. I wanted to get the questions where a USER answered first. I am adding my answer.